# Error timeout when I want to read file from hadoop with pyspark

Tags: csv, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

I want to read a csv file from hadoop with Pyspark with the following code:

```
dfcsv = spark.read.csv("hdfs://my_hadoop_cluster_ip:9000/user/root/input/test.csv")
dfcsv.printSchema()
```

My cluster hadoop is on a Docker container on my local machine and link with two other slave container for the workers.

As you see in this picture from my [ui hadoop cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R49xR.png), the path is the right path.

But when I submit my script with this command :
`spark-submit --master spark://my_cluster_spark_ip:7077 test.py`

My script stuck on the read, and after few minutes I have this following error :

```
22/02/09 15:42:29 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.1 in stage 4.0 (TID 4) (my_slave_spark_ip executor 1): org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: Call From spark-slave1/my_slave_spark_ip to my_hadoop_cluster_ip:9000 failed on socket timeout exception: org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 20000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remote=my_hadoop_cluster_ip/my_hadoop_cluster_ip:9000]; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/SocketTimeout
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapWithMessage(NetUtils.java:792)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.wrapException(NetUtils.java:751)
...
```

For information, my csv file is very small, just 3 lines and 64 KB.

Have you any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: 1) Don't use IP's in Docker. Can you share any Compose file you're using? 2) You shouldn't need to refer to any HDFS port number 3) You shouldnt really be using HDFS for files that are much less than 128MB (yours is 148 bytes, not 64KB). I'd recommend MinIO docker image for file storage instead and using `s3a` spark reader

Comment: Hi @OneCricketeer and thanks for helping me, I don't use any compose file, I have one cluster spark in a docker container and others containers with my hadoop, I call it with the IP because i've done that with my cluster spark and it worked (but maybe a bad method). At first, I did not specify port number so my submit automatically go to the port 8020 and I had a `connection refused error`. Finally, I try in first with a 250MB but I change with a smaller file to test if the problem was from the file size.

Comment: If you're not using Compose and manually running each container, refer [docs on bridge networks](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) and using `--link`. Regarding the port problem, you're still getting a connection error. Your `core-site.xml` file is likely misconfigured; where do you set this? Both this and your networking setup between the containers would explain the error